# making an animation from a data file with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization

I have some c++ code which generates trajectories of particles. i. e. x and y coordinates of particles in different steps of simulations, in which the output file looks like this (for 4 particles):

```
#step0
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
#step1
1.2 2.2
3.2 4.3
5.2 6.4
7.2 8.5
...
```

I want to make an animation with **matplotlib** by reading data from this file. For doing this I changed a python code, but it just produces blank image.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
"""
Animation of Elastic collisions with Gravity

author: Jake Vanderplas
email: vanderplas@astro.washington.edu
website: http://jakevdp.github.com
license: BSD
Please feel free to use and modify this, but keep the above information. Thanks!
"""
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

N_step = 2
N_particle = 4

class ParticleBox:
    """Orbits class

    init_state is an [N x 4] array, where N is the number of particles:
       [[x1, y1, vx1, vy1],
        [x2, y2, vx2, vy2],
        ...               ]

    bounds is the size of the box: [xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax]
    """
    def __init__(self,
                 init_state = [[1, 0, 0, -1],
                               [-0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5],
                               [-0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 0.5]],
                 bounds = [-2, 2, -2, 2],
                 size = 0.04):
        self.init_state = np.asarray(init_state, dtype=float)
        self.size = size
        self.state = self.init_state.copy()
        self.time_elapsed = 0
        self.bounds = bounds

    def step(self, dt):
        """step once by dt seconds"""
        self.time_elapsed += dt
        **x,y = [], []                       
        with open("traj.xyz") as f:
            lines = f.readlines()

            Data = lines[(N_particle + 1)*self.time_elapsed:N_particle+(N_particle + 1)*self.time_elapsed] 
            for line in Data: 
                row = line.split()
                x.append(row[0])
                y.append(row[1])

        # update positions
        self.state[:, 0] = x
        self.state[:, 1] = y

#------------------------------------------------------------
# set up initial state
np.random.seed(0)
init_state = -0.5 + np.random.random((4, 4))

box = ParticleBox(init_state, size=0.04)
dt = 1.

#------------------------------------------------------------
# set up figure and animation

fig = plt.figure()
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0, right=1, bottom=0, top=1)
axes = fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')
particles, = axes.plot([], [], 'bo')   

rect = plt.Rectangle(box.bounds[::2],
                     box.bounds[1] - box.bounds[0],
                     box.bounds[3] - box.bounds[2],
                     ec='none', lw=2, fc='none')
axes.add_patch(rect)

axes.grid()
axes.relim()
axes.autoscale_view(True,True,True)
#print x,y

def init():
    """initialize animation"""
    global box, rect
    particles.set_data([], [])
    rect.set_edgecolor('none')
    return particles, rect

def animate(i):
    """perform animation step"""
    global box, rect, dt, axes, fig
    box.step(dt)  
    # update pieces of the animation
    rect.set_edgecolor('k')
    particles.set_data(box.state[:, 0], box.state[:, 1])
    particles.set_markersize(10)
    return particles, rect

#plt.draw()?????
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=3,
                              interval=10, blit=True, init_func=init)
#ani.save('particle_box.mp4', fps=30, extra_args=['-vcodec', 'libx264'])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using the default bounds of the box, that's why (assuming your data is similar to the first two data points you posted) nothing shows in the box.

to fix this, change line 62
to something like this:

`box = ParticleBox(init_state,bounds = [-1, 10, -1, 10], size=0.04)`